# ARIA alert role for error messages

Tags: html, accessibility, wai-aria

Possibly related: [WAI ARIA alert on form submit (with page reloading)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20747488)

On a simple HTML form that submits to the server (no JavaScript)... if there are one or more errors, and the page is re-displayed with the same form, and a `<ul>` of error messages, should that list be marked up as:

```
<form ...>
    <ul role="alert">
        <li>Error 1</li>
        <li>Error 2</li>
    </ul>
    <!-- Fields -->
</form>
```

The reason I ask is because "elements with the role alert have an implicit aria-live value of assertive"... which makes me think that perhaps this is more for JavaScript inserting the errors into the DOM.

https://www.w3.org/TR/wai-aria/roles#alert

So this might not be any use for assistive devices (as its on the page to begin with)... and could possibly be harmful, as its not "live".

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Accessibility/ARIA/ARIA_Techniques/Using_the_alert_role

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would say you are right. Live regions are to show changing information on screen, hence "live". If there was AJAX, there would be a good case for an alert to say what went wrong. However, with a full post back to the server, I'd say it wouldn't be effective here.

I just tried this with NVDA on Firefox, it does (surprisingly) read the alert out as soon as the page is opened. However, you need to decide if this is the functionality you'd be going for.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks @craig-brett, that is very helpful, and is a good question... would someone using a user agent that detected the `role=alert` prefer it to be the first thing that is read on the page?... I know many moons ago a major issue for screen readers was the submission of a form and not knowing if it was successful (hence why I changed the page `<title>` to "An error has occurred").

Comment: @Craig-Francis, If you mean should user agents be reading things with role="alert" first thing even on full page refreshes, yeah I'd say so. Or if you meant would a user prefer an alert over some text on screen, maybe. I think that would vary from user to user. I personally don't mind it, but it may well be a misappropriation of live regions and it does feel slightly different. I think I noticed Linkedin uses a tactic like this though when you send a message, if that adds legitimacy.

Comment: Thats good to know, thanks @craig-brett ... I think I'll put it in for now, and see if I get any complaints or comments on how useful it is. Although I still find that people who rely on screen readers (or other systems) either don't use my websites, or don't comment on issues they find.

Answer (score 1):

As per the latest request I received from SSB Bart report, they are asking us to add role="alert" to each error message.

Comment: Is that a report specifically for your website, or a generic one that is available (and can be linked to) for everyone to read? Just trying to find as many references as possible :-)

Comment: Not publicly available but I can tell you that we have to have the same ADA requirements as most government sites. I actually had to add an additional attr declaration to the latest jQuery.Validate master file so that it generates a role="alert" on each error span.

Comment: Interesting... so the page potentially had many alert spans? I wonder if, because I'm showing a single list of errors at the top of the page, that would be any different (I personally like having a single list so all errors are in one place, and because they are in a <ul>, the number of errors can be read out by some user agents, e.g. screen readers).

Comment: Yeah it seems a bit odd to throw so many role="alert"'s on one page because they potentially could all show up at the same time. It's a matter of design preference to have them all in one single list or to below/above each field. In your case, I would think that the role="alert" could just be applied to the main UL for the errors. For me, I prefer to have them inline with the inputs so that there is a distinct variation in server response errors. It makes it easier to control the focus return one the UI validations pass and just have the focus on a new error div for any backend failures.